# Every push from one client corrupts upstream git repo

Tags: git

I have a git repo being hosted over SSH on a Linux machine.  This repo can be accessed and pushed to just fine from other Linux machines (CentOS, using git 1.7.1), but when one member of our team (who has been accessing it from his Windows machine using the currently available 1.9 release) tries to push to it, every time it corrupts the upstream repository, and we have to reset it and clean it up.

I am at a loss here, and the 'symptoms' are different each time, though they all have to do with invalid objects.  Here are some things that have happened (these were all run in the bare repo on the server):

```
$ git fsck --full
error: HEAD: invalid sha1 pointer f9e716400c3b446caffb306485f84a0481cc5d20
error: refs/heads/master does not point to a valid object!
notice: No default references
dangling commit 039e961c771bf757aa61168b5a9359e3a087dfb4
```

Another time:

```
$ git fsck --full
broken link from commit 10c236ff736d28d7cf01ac247dd63ac3f642aa6d
              to   tree 3f4ac6f0553c64b1848dbbde7f63230001a80acc
```

We have tried this several more times with similar results.  We tried downgrading him to msysgit 1.7, but the same things were happening.  I'm not sure how to diagnose this further.

Comment: Have you checked if the repo on the developer's machine is in OK shape? The main times I've seen things like this is when the repo that was pushed from was corrupted.

Comment: He makes a fresh `clone` for each attempt. We ran `git fsck -v` on both his machine and the server, and both were quite similar, except his was missing these invalid hashes and broken links.